# How can I load css file in Meteor for just one page?

Tags: css, meteor

I have three css files that I only want loaded on a specific page or template. How can this be done in Meteor. I have already tried appending the css files to the head area on template creation, but this doesn't work because those files stay loaded when I navigate away from this page.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456293/meteor-js-iron-router-apply-css-change-whenever-route-changes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with a very simple custom layout which adds the name of the template in the first div. On your main template:

```
<head>
  <title>Your title</title>
  ...
</head>

<template name="layout">
  <div class="container-fluid {{template}}">
    <header>
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      ...
    </header>
    <div class="row">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Add the following template helper:

```
Template.layout.helpers({
  template: function () {
    route = Router.current();
    return route? route.lookupTemplate() : 'home';
  },
  ...
});
```

Your CSS can now be isolated to a single page by simply adding your template's name as a root class, like so:

```
.templateName header h1 { color: red; }
.templateName div.row { max-height: 300px; }
...
```

Finally, remember to point Iron Router to your layout template:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  ...
});
```

Comment: How did you return the name of the template using {{template}} helper? What is the command? Thanks

Comment: This worked, but instead I just wrapped the template insert in a div like this <div class="Receip">{{> Receipt}}</div>. I then had to use .less files and wrap them as you suggested. Not sure why, but Meteor wouldn't let me wrap my CSS files with another CSS class.

Comment: @JoshOne I just added the missing template helper and changed the example to show CSS instead of LESS. Sorry about that.